# Write the SQL code that will list Physician-Person appointments only ONCE

Tags: sql, sql-server

This one is confusing me?

There are three tables. `Appointments(Appointment_ID, Physician_ID and Person_ID)` , `Physician(Physician_ID)` and a `Person(Person_ID and Physician_ID)`.

This is what I have so far :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Appointment_date_time FROM Appointment 
INNER JOIN Person 
        ON Appointment.Person_ID = Person.Person_ID
INNER JOIN Physician 
        ON Physician.Physician_ID = Person.Physician_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) < 1
```

Comment: You should include sample data and desire output. We dont know what you want so we cant help you yet.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: It is true that your `Person` table has two columns `Person_ID` and `Physician_ID`?

Comment: You've not asked a meaningful question. Your title is a statement that you want us to write code for you. Your only question shouldn't be - it's also a statement. You've not described a problem with the code you've posted, not provided database schema or sample data.

Comment: I expect it should be `physician.physician_id=appointment.physician_id`

Comment: Considering the title starts with "Write the SQL code...", this sounds eerily like a homework question.

Comment: No because I am joining the table Physician with Person table and the primary key to Physician table is Physician_ID and FK to Person table is Physician_ID.  The Physician table does not have a Person_ID.  I think the JOIN statements are correct, just not getting it.

Comment: You're not explaining the problem, and **still* have  not asked a question.

Comment: There are three tables.  Appointments(Appointment_ID, Physician_ID and Person_ID)  ,  Physician(Physician_ID) and a Person(Person_ID and Physician_ID).

Comment: The reason people do not want to help you is because 1) you have not conveyed what about the issue at hand is confusing, 2) You have not provided any data for anyone to use to try and replicate the issue, 3) You have not provided what you want the output to look like.  Juan did you a favor at the top of these comments by showing you how to post a question.

Comment: Dude i'm new here and just figuring stuff out. I apologize for not giving the community enough information or the quality of my question. I've figured it out. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

> There are three tables. Appointments(Appointment_ID, Physician_ID and Person_ID) , Physician(Physician_ID) and a Person(Person_ID and Physician_ID).

```
select *
from Appointments a
inner join Person p
on a.Person_ID = p.Person_ID
inner join Physician ph
on a.Physician_ID = ph.Physician_ID
```